# Android: Custom URI Scheme for launching application does not work

Tags: android, android-intent

We have Custom URI Scheme which is opened in Mobile Browser to open the application. We are facing a unique issue in it as specified below:

Steps:

- Install the application from command prompt / playstore but do not
  launch the application.
- Launch the application from the URI scheme (Browser page with link),
  application starts and goes to the activity which has intent filter
  for this uri scheme.
- Now navigate to some other activity and press home key from here.
- Again launch the application from URI , but it does not go the
  activity which has intent filter for this uri , instead it launches
  the recent open activity.

But when we run the application from Android Studio , the application is automatically launched next we press back and follow the above mentioned steps but we are not able to reproduce the above mentioned issue.

We are not able to identify the reason of different behaviour on different running mechanism.

Please let us know what might be the reason for this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Help Appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the app to open the same activity even if the app is already running you should use the [android:launchmode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) option in the activity block which has the uri scheme.

Comment: Hello, thanks for  the help but the launchmode option is feasible as it breaks application flow in another scenarios. We are not able to understand why the activity which listens to that intent filter is not opening up.